# Turning Python generator inside out for GRPC Streaming Endpoint

Tags: python, stream, generator, grpc

I have a GRPC server that streams back items to a client. The generation of these items however also depends on async events and various stuff. So I want to allow other components to call the grpc component and pass data to the client via a call. The data then gets sent to the open grpc connection.

This is what I have:

```
class SubmitService(ptac_grpc.SubmitServiceServicer):
    _order_gen: Generator = None

    def sendOrder(self, msg: ptac_pb2.PBOrder):
        if SubmitService._order_gen is not None:
            SubmitService._order_gen.send(msg)
        else:
            log.error("could not send order to server, no generator present")


    def getOrders(self, request, context):
        """DO NOT CALL from python. This is the API to the adapter"""
        SubmitService._order_gen = self._inside_out_gen()
        for msg in SubmitService._order_gen:
            yield msg

    def _inside_out_gen(self) -> Generator:
        while True:
            #turning a generator inside out
            yield (yield)
```

My GRPC Endpoint is called `getOrders`. It is called by the connecting client. The code above assumes there is just the one client for now. Would it work?

Comment: Off the top of my head, it seems to me it should work just fine. Each gRPC handler gets executed on the threadpool passed to `grpc.server` when creating the object, so this would be no different from having a bunch of Python threads spinning up your `getOrders` function. Have you tried running the code to see if there is any specific issues with it? Does it not work?

Comment: There is a fairly large discussion around this: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/6046 .

Comment: looks like that discussion is centered around `asyncio`-runtime based generators. I am not familiar with Python 3 `Generator` object, but does that require use of `asyncio` event loop under the hood? If so, then yeah that issue needs to be fixed and in the meantime, using a simple traditional iterator that waits on a `threading.Event` and `yield`s results may be a good workaround.